# Can we crop an image with point and size in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm writing a face detect app and I want to crop the face that have detected on screen with the bounding box of that face.

I have searched all the way but only can crop with width height and aspect ratio.

I don't want to crop manual like other image crop plugin because they also crop with width height and aspect ratio as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image for that.

For your case, try to use `copyCrop`.

https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/blob/master/lib/src/transform/copy_crop.dart

**copy_crop.dart**

```dart
import '../image.dart';

/// Returns a cropped copy of [src].
Image copyCrop(Image src, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
  Image dst = Image(w, h, channels: src.channels, exif: src.exif,
      iccp: src.iccProfile);

  for (int yi = 0, sy = y; yi < h; ++yi, ++sy) {
    for (int xi = 0, sx = x; xi < w; ++xi, ++sx) {
      dst.setPixel(xi, yi, src.getPixel(sx, sy));
    }
  }

  return dst;
}
```

**Usage**

```dart
var croppedImage = Image copyCrop(Image sampleImageSrc, int pointX, int pointY, int desiredWidth, int desiredHeight);
```

Comment: By the way, do you know how to convert Camera Image to Image? @JoshuadeGuzman

Comment: There's no easy way how to do it, but hope this thread could help you. 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26348

Comment: @hoangquyy what worked for me is getting the image as bytes image = _imageFile.readAsBytesSync() and then:  Image.memory(DartImage.encodePng(DartImage.copyCrop(DartImage.decodeImage(Uint8List image), x, y, w, h,) returns a Flutter Image (I defined package:image as DartImage here)

Comment: Does it work for animated webp and gif? It should crop but keep animation rather making it static image