# Flutter: in image package, how to save cropped image returned from copyCrop() to path?

Tags: image, flutter

Following on this question: [Can we crop an image with point and size in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57601908/can-we-crop-an-image-with-point-and-size-in-flutter)

I'm using the [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package on pub dev for cropping images. And the copyCrop returns an [image](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/Image-class.html). How could I save it to a local path? or possibly do some conversion and use it directly in an image widget?

Comment: the path? `copyCrop` returne an [Image](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/Image-class.html) - it does not have any path

Comment: Thank you! In that case, Let me update my question

Comment: if you just want to use it in `Image` widget then use `Image.memory(encodeJpg(croppedImage))` (or use `encodePng` / `encodeGif`) - you dont need to save it in your local filesystem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this method:

```
  import 'package:image/image.dart';


  var image = [some Image] as Image;

  await File('thumbnail.png').writeAsBytes(encodePng(image));
```

Comment: in  ```File('thumbnail.png').writeAsBytes(encodePng(image));```, 'thumbnail.png' could be replaced by the desired saving path, right?

Comment: Yes. If you want to save a file in application directory use path_provider and similar packages and don't import path as `thumbnail.png`.